# Linux lftp mv command with variable

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

I'm trying to read file name from a txt file and move files in a FTP server from one folder to another. I have the following command

```
grep '.rar' /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/download.txt | while read -r line ; do lftp -e 'set net:timeout 20; mv "Folder Name/${line}" "Folder Name/tmp/${OUTPUT}"; bye' -u username,password ftps://11.11.11.11:990 ; done
```

However, the ${$line} variable is not being replaced with values and the FTP server is showing

```
file/directory not found (Folder Name/${line})
```

Any pointer would be appreciated. (I'm on Centos 6.5 if that helps).

Comment: You have the whole command surrounded in single quotes and variables are not expanded within single quoted strings.  If you just reverse the single and double quotes in the `lftp` command it will probably work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the whole command single quoted, which prevents bash parameter expansion within.  You can fix that part by reversing the single and double quotes like so:

```
grep '.rar' /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/download.txt | while read -r line ; do lftp -e "set net:timeout 20; mv 'Folder Name/${line}' 'Folder Name/tmp/${OUTPUT}'; bye" -u username,password ftps://11.11.11.11:990 ; done
```

Assuming you have no files with newlines or single quotes this should work I expect.

To help protect against special characters you can use `printf` instead of just directly expanding in place like:

```
grep '.rar' /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/download.txt | while read -r line ; do lftp -e "set net:timeout 20; mv '$(printf 'Folder Name/%q' "${line}")' '$(printf 'Folder Name/tmp/%q' "${OUTPUT}")'; bye" -u username,password ftps://11.11.11.11:990 ; done
```

since we can use `printf` with `%q` to print a quoted/escaped string that can be used in the next layer of command

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you!